# passing variables and other variables

Tags: php, javascript, variables, echo

This is the IMDB code

http://pastie.org/private/s8m72fndjvqzdtcjjel5w

and in order to use it I must create another page by inserting this 
http://lab.abhinayrathore.com/imdb/usage.htm

I thought of an idea instead of creating an each page I tried to use passing variables via url
and somehow to put a variable or anything in getMovieInfo("INTHISPLACE");

```
$movieArray = $imdb->getMovieInfo("MovieName in here");
```

Instead of creating a new page and for each time for a single movie I wanted something like this site.com/movie.php?m=tt0068646 <

```
<?php
include("imdb.php");

$imdb = new Imdb();
$movieArray = $imdb->getMovieInfo
var getMovieInfo = $m;
$val = $_GET['m']; 
echo "$m"; 
echo '<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="2" border="1" width="80%" align="center">';
foreach ($movieArray as $key=>$value){
    $value = is_array($value)?implode("<br />", $value):$value;
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th align="left" valign="top">' . strtoupper($key) . '</th><td>' . $value . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

^ that didnt work because whenever I wrote site.com/movie.php?m=ANYKINDOFMOVIeCode it didnt bring me to the same movie or nowhere.

The Original Code:

```
<?php
include("imdb.php");

$imdb = new Imdb();
$movieArray = $imdb->getMovieInfo("MovieName in here"); 
echo '<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="2" border="1" width="80%" align="center">';
foreach ($movieArray as $key=>$value){
    $value = is_array($value)?implode("<br />", $value):$value;
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th align="left" valign="top">' . strtoupper($key) . '</th><td>' . $value . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

tried to add this to that ^:

```
$val = $_GET['m']; 
echo "$m";
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you're trying to accomplish. I see some JavaScript mixed in among PHP `ver getMovieInfo = $m` ??

Comment: Explain your problem here as a question, be more specific.

Comment: `^ that didnt work`. Can you be any more verbose here? How didn't it work?

Comment: there fixed it, it's more clear now.

Comment: Basically I want e.g: site.com/watch.php?m=tt0068647 and I want that code to be in the $m or $movieArray = $imdb->getMovieInfo("The Godfather"); replace TheGodfather

Comment: It's really still not clear what you are trying to do. You need to explain what you are trying to do EXACTLY. Explain what you want to do, what you've done, and what didn't work, BEFORE you add code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$imdb = new Imdb();
$movieArray = $imdb->getMovieInfo
var getMovieInfo = $m;
$val = $_GET['m']; 
echo "$m";
```

Should be

```
$imdb = new Imdb();
$movieArray = $imdb->getMovieInfo($_GET['m']);
```

Comment: Basically I want e.g: site.com/watch.php?m=tt0068647 and I want that code to be in the $m or $movieArray = $imdb->getMovieInfo("The Godfather"); replace TheGodfather

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can use that code. This will place the text you have in the URL, e.g. `site.com/watch.php?m=tt0068647` into the method `getMovieInfo`. So that will basically be `$movieArray = $imdb->getMovieInfo("tt0068647");`

Comment: There thanks, bro. Do you have any way I could contact you, it works perfectly, but loads slowly for some reason, is there a way you could help me? I was just testing it, your answer is the best now :P

Comment: Well, I don't know anything about the IMDB 'plugin', my answer was only based on syntax issues. The reason it's slow is most certainly that when the page loads, it needs to connect to IMDB and return the result based on your query, before your script continues. An alternative is to load the IMDB content via jQuery and AJAX. That will make the page load faster, and the IMDB content will load later. If you use a loader icon it won't look too bad.

Comment: Well it works fine now I need to add some background and stuff http://ivids.tk/test.php?m=tt0454349 and I want to making something like this http://freeflix.technoinsidr.com/watch.php?m=tt0092718 do you know how to add a form box which will include a box with the IMDB code and another box for links basically something like this http://mobilevids.org/uploader/addlinks.php and it will add a link to the page?